# How to disable JavaScript function in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to disable a JavaScript function within HTML code of an online website. Basically the function checks to see if a radio button is selected before being able to parse data from the HTML tags.

I am thinking of few options:

1. disable the function, so all the JavaScript will be ignored.
2. change the function from display="block" to display="none".
3. write a function to create a checked radio button and pretend to be the same
   button.
4. if none of above are possible then save the page and parse the data
   off-line.

Since I am new to JavaScript, your expertise is greatly appreciated on which and how to approach this issue.

Here is a part of the function:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
....
<script>
function disable_content()
{   
    if(!isRadioButtonselected('radio'))
    {
        document.getElementById('spamOverlayError').style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('spam_error').innerHTML="Please provide a flag"
        return false;           
    }
    if (!(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/.test(document.getElementById('rec_email').value))) 
    {
        document.getElementById('spamOverlayError').style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('spam_error').innerHTML ="Please fill valid email ID.";
        return false;
    }
      ....
}

....

function isRadioButtonselected(radioGrpName)
{
        var radios = document.getElementsByName(radioGrpName);
        var i;   
        for (i=0; i<radios.length; i=i+1 ){
           if (radios[i].checked){
              return true;
           }
        }
        return false;
}

    return "";
}
</script>
<body>
....
<div class="flag_this" onClick="display_pop_up('light_spam');document.getElementById('spamOverlayError').style.display='none';">  
<input type="hidden" name="PageReload" value="YES"   id="PageReload">
....
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the conditions to disable the function? Should it always be disabled?

Comment: If you declare two functions with the same name, the second one wins, so if you want to replace *isRadioButtonselected*, just declare another function with the same name that does whatever you want, e.g. to make it always return `true`, put `function isRadioButtonselected(){return true}` after the first declaration or initialisation.

Comment: BTW, exactly which bit of code are you trying to disable or modify?

Comment: Thanks RobG, I've tried to rewrite the function as you have suggested but it didn't work. I would like to unblock the display content (style.display="block";) on a server side function. I can view the content but since this function checks if a Radio button is selected from another page when I try to crawl the HTML tags automatically it returns null.

Comment: evuez, the function is running on a server site. It doesn't have to be disable all the time. I just need to disable it in order to parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this is an old post. If not resolved, you may try RobG's solution, like:

```
...
function disable_content()
{
    return false;
}
</script>
...
```

A cleaner approach will be searching your HTML page to find out which part calls this "disable_content()" function.

If it is in HTML like:

```
<button onClick="return disable_content()">Blah, blah</button>
```

You can clean it to be like:

```
<button>Blah, blah</button>
```

If it is in Javascript like:

```
var isContentDisabled = disable_content();
```

You may remove or comment out the Javascript line and following references to it, if any. Use F12 developer tool (Chrome/IE) or Firebug (Firefox) to debug to ensure your changes don't break something else.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using jquery:

```
$('selector').removeAttr('onclick');
```

This will remove onclick attribute.

Comment: The OP hasn't used a jQuery tag, there is no jQuery in the posted code, and it's not clear that that's what the OP wants to do. BTW, not my down vote.

Comment: Thanks guys, there is a jQuery function in the code, which I am not sure if it has main impact on hiding the HTML content from parsing.

Comment: function getHighTextUnEscaped() { return '' ;  }
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#comments').click(function(){
  jQuery('.popup_overlay').show();
                jQuery('.popup_wrapper').show();
                });
        jQuery('#close_popup').click(function(){
        jQuery('.popup_overlay').hide();
                jQuery('.popup_wrapper').hide();
                });
        if(getHighTextUnEscaped()){
                var hightext='"'+getHighTextUnEscaped()+'"';
                var high_n =  new Array();
                hightext = html_entity_decode(hightext);